# Displaying any point in youtube iframe initially

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I know that I can use embed parameters such as &start=10, but I would like to know if there is an option that could load the iframe showing a different time in the video for image purpose, and possibly still start at the beginning.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you set this in YouTube when you upload the video - I think it gives you options for which image you want to use, but last time I looked, it didn't allow you to set your own image for this.

Comment: @zenkaty If I can get away with being able to use an image/scene from the video itself for page load, that could work. But after looking, youtube seems to only have an option for start.

Comment: Does this help - http://www.squidoo.com/youtubeframe

Comment: @zenkaty In conclusions, unless you're a YouTube partner, that is the only way to change your video still frame. Thanks for the help, if you want best answer, post a conclusion below.

Comment: +1 for offering me the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube doesn't allow you to set custom frames as stills - I think it gives you some options to choose from when you upload your video, see more info here: http://www.squidoo.com/youtubeframe